# Tracking inconsistency in FX-hedged accumulating ETF

Tags: etf, foreign-exchange, dividend-reinvestment, hedging

I am looking at historical data for the **iShares S&P 500 GBP Hedged UCITS ETF (Acc)** Exchange Traded Fund (ETF), with Epic ID **IGUS**. The objective of the ETF is to track the performance of the S&P500 hedged back to GBP, in order to insulate against any PnL originating from moves in the GBPUSD FX rate (technically it seems to be tracking a GBP-version of the S&P500 but this should have no influence in practice I think):

> *The Fund seeks to track the performance of an index composed of 500 large cap U.S. companies which also hedges USD currency in the index back to GBP on a monthly basis.*

Now, according to the [webpage](https://www.ishares.com/uk/individual/en/products/251904/ishares-sp-500-gbp-hedged-ucits-etf) itself, IGUS is an **accumulating** ETF so that dividends are reinvested automatically. As far as I know this is not the case for the S&P500 index, which is calculated on a total return basis but assuming distribution of dividends, hence no compounding. Therefore, over long periods, I would expect the quotation of IGUS to gradually diverge upwardly with respect to the S&P index. However, when looking at historical data from investing.com for a) the S&P500 index, and b) the IGUS ETF, I actually find that IGUS tracks the S&P500 very closely (I have also added the evolution of IGUS with daily conversion to USD):

[image]

I would expect IGUS (red continuous line) to gradually diverge from the S&P500. **Why is that not the case?** It does not look to me like IGUS is reinvesting dividends, there is no compounding here. On the other hand, other S&P500 accumulating ETFs do show compounding effects even after expressed in GBP terms, such as [CSP1](https://www.ishares.com/uk/individual/en/products/253743/ishares-sp-500-b-ucits-etf-acc-fund). **Can anybody explain this?**